# Adding error class to outer div django widget-tweaks

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am currently working on forms with django-widget-tweaks, I want to add error class to div not in input, here is my code

```
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="id_title">Title</label>
{% render_field form.title|add_class:"form-control"%}
 </div>
```

if getting error it should be

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
 <label class="control-label" for="id_title">Title</label>
 <input type="text" name="title" value="akjdla" id="id_title" class="form- 
  control" required="" placeholder="Title" title="" maxlength="120">
  <div class="help-block">This field is required.</div>
  </div>
```

In documentation I found only adding the class in input, how can I add error class to outer div and show error down to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group" {% if form.title.errors %} has-error {% endif %}>
    <label class="control-label" for="id_title">Title</label>
    {{ form.title|add_class:"form-control" }}
    <div class="help-block">{{ form.title.errors }}</div>
</div>
```